# OSGi Declarative Services and Config Admin

Tags: configuration, osgi, declarative-services

I'm writting bundle with declarative services usage. For configuration I'm using properties in DS declaration. Those props can be normally changed by Config Admin, but they are not persisted. After container restart, component has default values.

I'am using Config admin like this:

```
Configuration c = configurationAdmin.getConfiguration(UserAgent.SERVICE_PID, null);
System.out.println(c.getProperties()); // every time is null!
Dictionary props = new Hashtable();
props.put(UserAgent.PROPERTY_PORT, 5555);
c.update(props);
```

and in component I have:

```
// ...

@Modified
public void updated(ComponentContext context) {
    config = context.getProperties();
    init();
}

@Activate
protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {
    config = context.getProperties();
    init();
}
//...
```

I'm using Felix, properties file is stored in cache

```
service.bundleLocation="file:bundles/cz.b2m.osgi.phonus.core_1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar"
service.pid="cz.b2m.osgi.phonus.sip"
port=I"5555"
```

But after restart isn't loaded. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for all tips.

Comment: FYI, you may want to use the <operation>(Map properties) signature for your activate/deactivate/modified operations to avoid having OSGi APIs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in Pax Runner which every restart (clean) erased the data folder of Config Admin bundle.

To make sure that Pax Runner does not clear the data, you can use the `--usePersistedState=true` flag.